# Generate token for

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-rest-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctions

[image]

How can I generate the token highlighted in green dynamically using JavaScript or an Api? I know it can be generated using Azure CLI `az account get-access-token` but that does not fit my solution to help me monitor my functions programmatically.

Comment: bearer token is generate from ad authorize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [acquire the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token) either using the OAuth2 service endpoints, or MSAL. OAuth2 endpoints are Platform- and language-neutral, but MSAL is not.

The two Azure AD endpoints that you use to authenticate your client and acquire an access token are referred to as the OAuth2 `/authorize` and `/token` endpoints. How you use them depends on the type of OAuth2 authorization grant flow you need to support your app.

For instance, a non-interactive client can use client credentials grant, wherein the access token can be acquired by sending a [POST request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to the `/token` endpoint.

From Postman:

[image: Get AAD Token v2.0]

For more information, refer to the [Azure REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).